# JMeter external JSR223 java edited in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

I'd like to reach that point where I have a development environment with the following attributes:

- JMeter tests consist of JSR 233 scripts mainly
- JSR 233 scripts are written in Java
- I can edit the java code in IntelliJ
- the project is a maven project

So far I could do everything from the list above except IntelliJ support. So, I add a JSR 233 PreProcessor script to the test using JMeter GUI, I setup the script path. When I create the .java file and start to edit in Intellij following [examples](https://blazemeter.com/blog/creating-jmeter-variables-in-java-the-ultimate-guide/) IntelliJ gets crazy, since the code is not enclosed in a `class {}`. As a result I can't leverage on IntelliJs capabilities and great support in java.

Is there any way to configure IntelliJ to support these script files?

I double checked how the example Java code is stored in the jmx file, and it is not enclosed in a `class {}`.

**Why not Groovy?** you might ask. The reason is that, when I made a mistake in groovy script it doesn't cause build failure, it will give me a runtime error. I consider this not effective enough, however groovy is plan C.

Plan B is all java code gets into an external jar and will be included in minimal groovy script.

I would really appreciate if you could help with answers or any articles probably answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java scripting code is actually running [Beanshell language](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell)

You have [BeanShell Box](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1022-beanshell-box) plugin that support your requirement in Intellij

> Adds a BeanShell toolbox allowing you to write snippets of both Java and BeanShell code.

Benshell file extension is .bsh usually

Comment: I mark this answer the right answer, however the plugin fails at start.

Comment: @SayusiAndo Can you add your issue to plugin page ? I'm using Eclipse

Comment: Done, but this plugin was update last time in 2010! It is dead now, IMHO.